# Move getCmsBlockHtml() from category view to sidebar

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

I'm trying to move the static CMS block from the category view into the sidebar. In my themename/template/catalog/category/view.phtml it is called with

```
$this->getCmsBlockHtml()
```

Since it's defined as

```
 /**
   * Retrieve current category model object
   *
   * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
   */
  public function getCurrentCategory()
  {
      if (!$this->hasData('current_category')) {
          $this->setData('current_category', Mage::registry('current_category'));
      }
      return $this->getData('current_category');
  }

  public function getCmsBlockHtml()
  {
      if (!$this->getData('cms_block_html')) {
          $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
              ->setBlockId($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage())
              ->toHtml();
          $this->setData('cms_block_html', $html);
      }
      return $this->getData('cms_block_html');
  }
```

I've tried adding this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(   $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()    )->toHtml()
```

into my themename/template/callout/left-col.phtml file, but this throws errors.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the `getCurrentCategory()` method is defined in the category view block  Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View, thus the left-col.phtml template doesn't have any refference to it.
So instead of calling `getCurrentCategory()` method to get the category, you can get it from the registry: `Mage::registry('current_category')`

So, you can try changing your code to this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId( Mage::registry('current_category')->getLandingPage() )->toHtml()
```